# Probability question. Find the probability that the data set falls within 45% to 52% of the data set

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

One of your employees has suggested that your company develop a new product. A survey is designed to study whether or not there is interest in the new product. The response is on a 1 to 5 scale with 1 indicating definitely would not purchase, · · ·, and 5 indicating definitely would purchase. For an initial analysis, you will record the responses 1, 2, and 3 as No, and 4 and 5 as Yes.

a. 5 people are surveyed. What is the probability that at least 3 of them answered Yes?

b. 100 people are surveyed. What is the approximate probability that between 45% to 52% of people answered Yes?

For part a) There are 5 choices that people can respond by 1, 2 ,3 ,4 and 5. Since 1, 2 and 3 are considered "No", the probability of someone answering "No" is 3/5. For choices 4 and 4, the probability of someone responding with that is 2/5.

This looks like it fallows a binomial distribution so I calculated the probability of P(3) + P(4) + P(5).

However for part b), I'm confused. I can calculate the probability of someone saying yes but I don't know how to calculate the probability that a percentage of people saying yes. Does anyone know how to approach this question? I though about using the Z table, but that already calculates area.

Comment: Is the assumption that the people surveyed make their choices at random, with each choice equally likely?  (Does not bode well for the survey, if so.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the number of people answering yes. Then $X$ is a bionomial random variable.

Let $n$ denote the number of trials (i.e. people surveyed). Let $p$ denote the probability of a yes-response on a given trial, and let $q$ denote the probability of a no-response. Then, as you've argued, we have
$$ p = 2/5, \qquad q = 3/5. $$
Then in part (a), the probability of at least three people answering yes is 
$$ P(x = 3) + P(x = 4) + P(x=5) = \ldots. $$
So far so good!

Now for part (b):

You see, $45%$ of $1000$ is $450$, and $52%$ of $1000$ is $520$. So I reckon the probability you want is 
$$
\begin{align}
 P(X = 450) + P(X = 451) + \cdots + P(X = 520) &= \sum_{r = 450}^{520} P(X = r) \\
&= \sum_{r = 450}^{520} {1000 \choose r} \left( \frac{2}{5} \right)^r \left( \frac{3}{5} \right)^{1000 - r } \\
&= \cdots 
\end{align}
$$